# AJAX loads content twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to build a sidebar navigation, which uses AJAX to load content inside a div. 
So far it is working great, it is just that i noticed, that everytime i click onto the buttons to navigate to a different site on my page, the site content seems to be loaded on top of the current content.

I have got this hypothesis, because on every site load my site sends one request to a server, to get data from there.

Now if i already visited the site on my page, that sends this request, navigate to a different site on my page and navigate back to the first site, this site sends two requests to the server. 
If i am repeating those steps, it just adds up and the request gets sent 3,4,5..times

This is the Code of my navigation bar:

```
<div id="sidedrawer" class="mui--no-user-select">
  <div class="mui-divider"></div>
  <ul>
    <li onClick="remote();" href="./#remote">
      <strong><a href="./#remote" class="navbarlink">Remote</a></strong>
    </li>
    <li onClick="groups();" href="./#groups">
        <strong><a href="./#groups"  class="navbarlink">Groups</a></strong>
    </li>
    <li onClick="devices();" href="./#devices">
      <strong><a href="./#devices"  class="navbarlink">Devices</a></strong>
    </li>
    <li onClick="users();" href="./#users">
      <strong><a href="./#users"  class="navbarlink">Users</a></strong>
    </li>
    <li onClick="programs();" href="./#programs">
      <strong><a href="./#programs"  class="navbarlink">Programs</a></strong>
    </li>
    <li onClick="settings();" href="./#settings">
      <strong><a href="./#settings"  class="navbarlink">Settings</a></strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The functions remote()/groups()/devices() look about the same:

```
function remote() {
            showSubPage("Remote", "./remote.php");  
        }
```

showSubpage() looks like this:

```
function showSubPage(title, page){
    changeTabName(title);
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success:function(data){
                                var $main = $('#main');
                                $main.html('');
                                $main.html(data);                               
                                }
    });

}
```

Main is just a  normal div:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

Does anyone have an idea why my page does not get called just once everytime i click the links?

Edit:
When i am looking into the source code of my page, the content is only listed once.

Edit2: I figured that the problem does not come from the ajax itself. 
This is the PHP-code that i am using to generate my page.

```
function addGroup($groupId, $groupname, $devicearr)
    {
    echo('<div class="group">
            <h3>'.$groupname);
        echo('<div class="verticalcenter"><div class="toggle-button toggle-button-selected " id="groupButton'.$groupId.'"><button></button></div></div>');
    echo('      </h3>
            <div>
                <table class="devicetable">
                  ');

                  foreach ($devicearr as &$device) {
                        echo('<tr>
                                <td>'.$device['name'].'</td>');
                        if($device['status'] == 1){
                            echo('<td class="togglecolumn"><div class="verticalcenter" ><div class="toggle-button toggle-button-selected group'.$groupId.' device'.$device['id'].'" id="group'.$groupId.'device'.$device['id'].'" ><button></button></div></div></td></tr>');
                        } else {
                            echo('<td class="togglecolumn"><div class="verticalcenter"><div class="toggle-button group'.$groupId.' device'.$device['id'].'" id="group'.$groupId.'device'.$device['id'].'"><button></button></div></div></td></tr>');
                        }
                        echo ('<script>
                                        $(document).on("click","#group'.$groupId.'device'.$device['id'].'", function() {
                                            if($("#group'.$groupId.'device'.$device['id'].'").hasClass("toggle-button-selected")){
                                                $(".device'.$device['id'].'").removeClass("toggle-button-selected");
                                                    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
                                                    frame.src = "http://localhost/callMethod";
                                                    frame.style.left = "-9999px";
                                                    frame.style.display = "none";
                                                    frame.onload = function() {
                                                        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);    
                                                    };
                                                    document.body.appendChild(frame);

                                            }
                                            else{
                                                $(".device'.$device['id'].'").addClass("toggle-button-selected");
                                                var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
                                                frame.src = "http://localhost/callMethod";
                                                frame.style.left = "-9999px";
                                                frame.style.display = "none";
                                                frame.onload = function() {
                                                    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);    
                                                };
                                                document.body.appendChild(frame);
                                            }            
                                        });

                                    </script>');
                    }
    echo('
                </table>
            </div>
          </div>');

}
```

My code creates a button for each "device" that is in the "devicearr". But when my page got called twice and i click the button once, it registers two click events.

Comment: Example of what is returned in data?

Comment: From what you've shown the click handler should (and does) only execute once: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1hesztbt/. We'd need to see a working example of the problem to be able to help you

Comment: Why not `$main.load(page,callback)`?

Comment: The behaviour you describe it like something is subscribing a listener each time you click the sidebar menu, without removing previous listeners.

Comment: After Rory McCrossan's answer i figured, that the problem did not come from the ajax itself. It must be somewhere inside my JS. I will post the content of the remote.php page, which is loaded

Comment: PHP is returning a script that binds click handlers. So every time you perform the AJAX call, it's going to bind the click handlers again.

Comment: But shouldn't the click handlers disappear when i am loading the content again via ajax? How can i delete the click handlers on every call of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 $(document).on("click","#group'.$groupId.'device'.$device['id'].'", function() {
});
```

I used:

```
$("#group'.$groupId.'device'.$device['id'].'").click( function() {

});
```

so that the Click-Event does not stay alive after reloading the ajax content.

Additionally (not necessarily needed), i also unbind the click-event, before i register the click-event with:

```
$("#group'.$groupId.'device'.$device['id'].'").off("click");
```

Thanks to Barmar for the hint.